# I can not print

Tags: python-3.x, function, printing

```
import sys

def display_msg(expediteur, message ):
    print ("["), heure, ("]") ("<"),expediteur, (">"), message

heure = "12:00"
expediteur = "me"
message = "hey"
```

`

I would like to print:

```
[12:00] <me> hey
```

how to do ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have your tried reading the Python docs about [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)?

Comment: Your message would also be more likely to get an answer if you included what kind of error you get and what you tried...

Answer (score 0):

Use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
def display_msg(heure, expediteur, message):
    print ("[{}] <{}> {}".format(heure, expediteur, message))

heure = "12:00"
expediteur = "me"
message = "hey"

display_msg(heure, expediteur, message)
```

Output:

```
[12:00] <me> hey
```